# JQuery function to change iframe SRC and load in Jquery popup window

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have this JQuery code:

```
$("#EditCustomerA").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#EditCustomer").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  JQueryPopup('#EditCustomer');
});
```

and my JQueryPopup function is:

```
function JQueryPopup(value) {
    $(value).toggle();

    $('#JQueryClose').click(function(){
        $(value).hide();
    });

    $( document ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        $(value).hide();
    });

    $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
        if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
            $(value).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

The function works fine when i call it normally, however when i use:

```
<a id="EditCustomerA" href="editcustomer.php?seq=123">Link</a>
```

it just opens my page in a normal window.

I want to be able to load the `a href` link into my `iframe` (first jQuery function) then open the popup window using my `JQueryPopup` function

```
<div id="EditCustomer" class="EditPagePopup">
    <iframe id="EditCustomer" width="100%" height="100%" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Your link is calling `editcustomer.php?seq=123` directly.  Change it to `<a id="EditCustomerA" href="#">Link</a>` - The `onclick` listener you created will handle the click as expected (barring any other bugs)

Comment: just tried that but still nothing

Comment: did you get any error messages?

Comment: check fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2fgLn/

Comment: updated your fiddle, see if that works: http://jsfiddle.net/2fgLn/2/

Comment: in the console i get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: add a semi-colon at the end of `$("#EditCustomerA").click(function(e) {...})`

Comment: ok, i just added an alert after the JQueryPopup function, the popup window displays but as soon as i close the alert the popup window closes

Comment: updated fiddle, using `on('click',...` instead - http://jsfiddle.net/2fgLn/4/

Comment: same again, if i have the alert under the JQueryPopup function as soon as i close the alert the popup window closes

Comment: check this to prove the above - http://jsfiddle.net/2fgLn/5/

Comment: I can't (that's why this is hard to pinpoint) as I don't have access to your URL: `editcustomer.php?seq=123`

Comment: we don't want to hide the `$(value)` but the iframe so I updated the fiddle once more: http://jsfiddle.net/2fgLn/7/

Answer (score 0):

Your `iframe` and its parent both have the same `id`.

Changed it into:

**HTML**

```
<div id="EditCustomer" class="EditPagePopup">
    <iframe id="EditCustomerFrame" width="100%" height="100%" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<a id="EditCustomerA" href="#" value="editcustomer.php?seq=123">Link</a>
```

**JS**

```
$("#EditCustomerA").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#EditCustomerFrame").attr("src", $(this).attr("value"));
    $("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    JQueryPopup('#EditCustomer');

    console.log('test');
});

function JQueryPopup(value) {
    console.log( value );
    $(iframe).toggle();

    $("#JQueryClose").on('click', function (e) {
        $(iframe).hide();
    });

    console.log( '1');

    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        $(iframe).hide();
    });

    console.log( '2');

    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { // ESC
            $(iframe).hide();
        }
    });

    console.log( '3');
}
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: i just added an alert after the JQueryPopup function, the popup window displays but as soon as i close the alert the popup window closes